# Laravel inertia large file size and long load time

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, inertiajs

I am working on Laravel Inertia project.
app.js on local is 4MB
When I load the same file on live server then it becomes 13-15MB.
due to which page load time increases to 10-15 seconds.

I push file after compressing it by **npm run prod**

**Local Response time**
[image: file size on local]

**Live Response time**
[image: On server]

Everything is working great on local and live except file size issue.

**app.js**

```
require('./bootstrap');

// Import modules...
import { createApp, h } from 'vue';

import mitt from 'mitt';
const emitter = mitt();
import { App as InertiaApp, plugin as InertiaPlugin } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';
import { InertiaProgress } from '@inertiajs/progress';
const el = document.getElementById('app');


const app = createApp({
render: () =>
    h(InertiaApp, {
        initialPage: JSON.parse(el.dataset.page),
        resolveComponent: (name) => 
    require(`./Pages/${name}`).default,
           }),
    })
.mixin({ methods: { route } })
.use(InertiaPlugin)
});
app.config.globalProperties.emitter = emitter;
app.mount(el);
InertiaProgress.init({ color: '#124664',showSpinner:false });
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': path.resolve('resources/js'),
        },
    },
};
```

**webpack.mix.js**

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.vue()
.postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css/tailwind_css', [
    require('postcss-import'),
    // require('tailwindcss'),
    require('autoprefixer'),
])
.webpackConfig(require('./webpack.config'));

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();
}
```

app.js is added in main blade in head tag file like this

```
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

Comment: Did you check if you maybe have gzip compression running local but not on your production server?

Comment: I haven't implemented it on my local or live server

Comment: You could test by activating via htaccess on your server and compare if the filesize in network-tab changes.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is probably because you haven't configured Code Splitting correctly, which is causing all your files to be bundled into a single huge file.

You need to replace the synchronous `require` statement in you `app.js` with a **dynamic import**:

```js
render: () =>
    h(InertiaApp, {
        initialPage: JSON.parse(el.dataset.page),
        resolveComponent: (name) => 
           require(`./Pages/${name}`).default, // This line is bundling all your files together
        }),
    })
```

```js
render: () =>
    h(InertiaApp, {
        initialPage: JSON.parse(el.dataset.page),
        resolveComponent: (name) => 
           import(`./Pages/${name}`), // Now, each page will have its respective file
        }),
    })
```

Laravel mix will probably handle the tooling need for Webpack to handle dynamic imports, but in case you're having troubles, take a look at [the docs which explains what you'll need in details](https://inertiajs.com/client-side-setup).

Comment: I have changed required to import. But it shows `Component is missing template or render function`.
Laravel-mix is also installed, it should work, but its not showing anything on screen.

Comment: It worked with promise.
`resolveComponent: (name) => import(`./Pages/${name}`).then((res) => res.default)`

Comment: but it as increased compile time a lot. Also no difference in performance on server